# Runtime class method replacement during initialisation

Tags: c++, methods, initialization, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Say I have a class which contains a method `speak()` which will print something to the terminal. What exactly it will print out is determined by an initialisation boolean, if true, it will print "Foo", if false, it will print "Bar". The value of the boolean value is determined at runtime.

One way to implement this would be to add an `if` statement in the `speak()` function which would then call either the `foo()` or `bar()` method. However, if this class method was called frequently, then the `if` switch and the additional function call could be avoided by instead replacing the `speak()` function by either the `foo()` or `bar()` function at class initialisation. Is there a way to achieve this functionality using, perhaps using function points?

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass (const bool select)
    {
        if (select)
        {
            // Make speak() use foo();
        }
        else
        {
            // Make speak() use bar();
        }
    }

    speak() const;

  private:
    foo() const { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
    bar() const { std::cout << "Bar\n"; }
}
```

It seems like this kind of behaviour would be beneficial, and therefor I assume there's some way of achieving it. However, I haven't had any luck in finding how to do this, mainly because I'm not sure exactly what to google.

Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: I think this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898316/using-a-member-function-pointer-within-a-class is about a similar idea. Maybe the answers will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like this kind of behaviour would be beneficial, and therefor I assume there's some way of achieving it.

Yes, it is possible using a member function pointer.

1. Declare a member variable that is a member function pointer.

   ```
     void (MyClass::*speaker)() const;
   ```
2. Initialize it appropriately in the constructor.

   ```
   MyClass (const bool select)
   {
      if (select)
      {
         speaker = &MyClass::foo;
      }
      else
      {
         speaker = &MyClass::bar;
      }
   }
   ```
3. Use it in `speak`.

   ```
   void speak() const
   {
      (this->*speaker)();
   }
   ```

Read more about member function pointers at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer.

Here's [a working example](https://ideone.com/MMtDEQ):

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
   public:

      MyClass (const bool select)
      {
         if (select)
         {
            speaker = &MyClass::foo;
         }
         else
         {
            speaker = &MyClass::bar;
         }
      }

      void speak() const
      {
         (this->*speaker)();
      }

      void (MyClass::*speaker)() const;

   private:
      void foo() const { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
      void bar() const { std::cout << "Bar\n"; }
};

int main()
{
   MyClass m1(true);
   MyClass m2(false);

   m1.speak();
   m2.speak();
}
```

and its output:

```
Foo
Bar
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the behaviour I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not just a matter to storing the value passed to the constructor and using it in a conditional in speak()?

```
class MyClass
{
  private:
    bool mselect;
  public:
    MyClass (const bool select)
    {
       mselect = select;
    }

    void speak()
    {
        if(mselect)
            std::cout << "Foo\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Bar\n";
    }
```

};

Or am I missing some part of this problem?  Sorry, would post as comment but don't have reputation yet.

Comment: The example was just an abstraction of the actual problem. The `foo()` and `bar()` classes do something much more complicated in reality. Whilst your suggestion would definitely work, it's probably not the most efficient method , as it requires checking the value of `mselect` at each call to `speak()`, and then potentially a resultant call to another method. The aim was to effectively replace the `speak()` method with the desired method.